# How to receive a string containing '\0' in socket developemnt?

Tags: string, windows, sockets, recv

When developing a socket project I found out that, the string containing '\0' cannot be received successfully thorugh `recv()` . '\0' seems to be considered as a termination that the rest of the string will be ignored. Is it possible that the string containing '\0' be sent and received correctly in socket implementation? What should I do to deal with this? Any suggestion or hint is appreciate.

my code listed as follows:

```
/*code in client-side*/
char sendData[4] = {'4','\0','4'};// sendData is just initilaized simply for test
//some other codes...
int s = send(sclient, sendData, 3, 0);// the 3rd parameter is set manually for test
```

But the array is still not sent entirely to the server-side since the return value of `recv()` in server-side is 1.

Comment: `recv` isn't the problem, printing the string is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the problem is, the return value of  `recv()` indicates the length of stream of what it receive, right? If so, the return value of such char array {'4',‘\0’,'4'} is 1 (observed from the complier) rather than 3. In this case, `recv()` does not receive the entire array. Correct me kindly plz if anything wrong.

Comment: Did you _send_ the entire array?

Comment: U got the point! I found out that I cannot send the entire array when containing '\0'. So one more question here, how to `send()` the entire array successfully since the arrary will be recognized as {'4'} when inputted as the 2nd parameter of `send()`.

Comment: You _can_ send the entire array. How exactly do you send it? Can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I edited my post. Hope it would be helpful for resolving this problem.

Comment: Looks good to me. Did you check wireshark to see whats _actually_ transmitted?

Comment: @tuziYou `int s = send(sclient, sendData, 3, 0);` will happily send the content of `sendData` *up to* 3 bytes (check `s` to know how many bytes were *actually* sent), regardless of what the values of the bytes are. `send()` doesn't care about `\0`, but functions like `strlen()` do. So make sure you are not *treating* `sendData` as a null-terminated C-style string before/when giving it to `send()`. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] showing exactly how `send()` is being used in the context of your other code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your answer. As shown in my post, `sendData` is initialied at frst and is not being processed before being put into `send()`. I have no idea about what's going wrong in this case. :(

Comment: @tkausl Thanks for reply. The complier has shown that I failed to send the enctire array. So is it necessary to check transmission using wireshark?

Comment: @tuziYou "*As shown in my post, `sendData` is initialied at frst and is not being processed before being put into `send()`*" - that is NOT apparent in your post, because you did not show any of the code *between* the initialization of `sendData` and the passing of it to `send()`. If we go solely on what IS shown in your post, then what you describe cannot happen, so it has to be related to something NOT shown in your post. That is why you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @tuziYou "*The complier has shown that I failed to send the enctire array*" - the *compiler* doesn't tell you that, the *return value* of `send()` does. Is that what you meant? What value is `s` being set to in `int s = send(sclient, sendData, 3, 0);`? If it is not 3, then it is not sending the whole array, and you will have to call `send()` again to re-send any unsent portion of `sendData`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I double checked my code that I did not do anything about `sendData` before being put into `send()`. I found out that I misunderstand meaning of the return value of `send()`. The array is actually sent but shown to be not according to the execution summary in the console. Thanks so much for answer this question!!!

Comment: @tkausl I would like to apologize for my careless that I misunderstand the return value of `send()` and rely on execution summary in console to confirm whether the entire array is sent. U are right at first, it is NOT the problem to `send()/recv()` but how to show the execution result, e.g., using `printf()`. But I still wonder why the return value of `recv()` will be 0 when receiving a string/an array that is actually not null but just started with '\0'.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One more question, plz. I still wonder why the return value of `recv()` will be 0 when receiving a string/an array that is actually not null but just started with '\0'. Or is there anything wrong?

Comment: @tuziYou `recv()` returns 0 when the connection has been closed gracefully by the other party. And FYI, it is possible to print the entire array with `printf()`, even if the array contains `\0`.  Just be sure to include the return value of `recv()`/`send()` in the `%s` specifier, eg: `int s = ...; printf("%.*s", s, sendData);`